# Cant change colour of searchBar and it jumps to top of view when selected

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, ios11

I'm trying to attach a search bar to the top of my tableView and change its attributes (eg. colour, placeholder). However, I can't figure out how. I've tried embedding the `tableView` in another view but that didn't help. Any ideas?

```
func setupSearch(){
    search.delegate = self
    search.automaticallyShowsCancelButton = false
    search.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
    search.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
    search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    search.searchBar.placeholder = "Type something here to search"
    navigationItem.searchController = search
    tableView.tableHeaderView = search.searchBar
}
```

This function is called in the viewDidLoad() and the tableView is added but not with the right colour or placeholder and jumps to the top of the screen when selected.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is the updated code for setupSearch (everything is working fine except the bar jumps to the top when selected):

```
func setupSearch(){
        search.delegate = self
        search.automaticallyShowsCancelButton = false
        search.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
        search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        tableView.tableHeaderView = search.searchBar
    }
```

I declare the search bar at the start using:

```
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

Any ideas on how to stop the bar jumping to the top?

Answer (score 1):

Just add search bar as tableview's headerview not with navigation's item searchcontroller(not add search bar with both(tableview and navigation) as in your code). You can try with updated code below:

```
func setupSearch(){
    search.delegate = self
    search.automaticallyShowsCancelButton = false
    search.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
    search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    search.searchBar.placeholder = "Type something here to search"
    tableView.tableHeaderView = search.searchBar
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

Comment: That solves the first problem so thank you. However the search bar still jumps to the top of the view when selected. Any ideas on that?

Comment: can you try to add navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I put it in but it had no effect. Maybe its to do with the declaration (let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil))?

Comment: So what am I doing wrong? I declare search at the very start.

Comment: It does not add the search bar to the table view using this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  setupSearch()
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil) // be notified when the keyboard changes your table View frame

   }


@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
   tableView.frame.origin.y = 0 // reset the table view to its original coordinates 

}


 func setupSearch(){

 // for iOS 12 and lower, you can change the placeholder like this :

 let textFieldSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
  textFieldSearchBar?.textColor = .red

  let searchBarLabel = textFieldSearchBar!.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
  textFieldSearchBarLabel?.textColor = .red

 }
```